# highcharts datetime x-axis custom formatting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I would like to have just the first letter of each weekday as the x-axis, ie M T W T F S S repeated.  Currently you can set `dateTimeLabelFormats`, which I've set to use `%a`, which is the dateFormat for short weekday (Mon Tues Wed etc).  How can I just use the first letter?

Here's my code (I'm using Lazy Highcharts in rails)

```
 f.xAxis({type: 'datetime', tickInterval: 24*3600*1000, dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%a',
        week: '%a'}
        })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the label -> formatter for xAxis, use dateFormat function to get the month and then use the substring function to get the first letter and return that letter as follows -

```
xAxis: {        
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            var monthStr = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value);
            var firstLetter = monthStr.substring(0, 1);
            return firstLetter;
        }
    }
},
```

[**See it on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/J7QX4/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. That fiddle depends on the Highcharts library amd the js file link isn't available anymore. But found the file in their new CDN. Now it's working again. :)

Comment: Can day of the week(sun.mon etc) be added somehow to x-axis label along with date and month???

Comment: @Nisha: It sure should be possible. But you should ask your own question. ;)

Comment: I found out.. it is possible..was just a little lazy to post a question :)